# Installing PHPUnit on MAMP 2.1.3 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: phpunit, osx-mountain-lion, mamp

I'm struggling with this issue.
Here's what I've tried :

```
$ cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/
$ sudo ./pear channel-update pear.php.net
$ sudo ./pear upgrade pear
$ sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
$ sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
$ sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

So it seems to work, but phpunit is actually installed in

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php3/bin/
```

If I tried to launch it from there, it doesn't work (no output, no log). If I move it to the php 5.4.10 folder, it still doesn't work.

I've replaced the Mac OS php cli with MAMP's :

```
$ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
```

As suggested on some website, I've also tried to remove

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/pear.conf
```

But nothing seems to help.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd recommend using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/). It's becoming a standard.

To start with, go to your project's root directory first and create a `composer.json` file there:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src"}
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    }
}
```

You can tune it to your needs later. You'll probably want to configure the autoloading if you'd like to leverage composer's autoloader (which I recomend).

Next download the composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

The above script will not only download it but also verify your environment if it's suitable to run composer binary.

If everything goes well install your dependencies:

```
./composer.phar install --dev
```

PHPUnit binary will be installed in the bin directory (configured in `composer.json`):

```
./bin/phpunit --version
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Composer could be used for phpunit ! It feels strange for me that I need one copy per project, but it could make sense also.

Comment: You can install stuff globally. However, I actually think it's good you have a separate copy for each project, since you could need different versions (not case for phpunit though).

Comment: Yeah, also it's easier to install packages on other machines... I guess I'm starting to understand Composer's value ! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've met this problem this morning and find this topic but no answer is helpful. After a couple of hours google search, I found this link, it helped me solve my problem
http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/macosx/installing-phpunit-on-mamp

My MAMP php version is 5.5.3
First, you'll probably need to update PEAR:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pear channel-update pear.php.net

sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pear upgrade pear
```

After that, add the appropriate PEAR channels for PHPUnit:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pear channel-discover components.ez.no
```

Finally, install PHPUnit:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Test phpunit to make sure it was installed correctly:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/phpunit --version
```

Link phpunit to your path

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Hope this help you and anyone meet this problem in the future!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [solution from this site](http://jeffreybarke.net/2010/08/how-to-install-phpunit-with-mamp/)
The php bin could vary from installation.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear channel-discover components.ez.no
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```