# mcrypt and PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mcrypt

I am using PHPUnit to test a project where mcrypt is heavily used. I have installed phpunit using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716993/installing-phpunit-on-mamp-2-1-3-mountain-lion).

Whenever I try and run `phpunit`, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in
/files/file/using/mcrypt/thing.php on line 20
```

How can I fix this error? Do I have to install mcrpyt especially for PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0):

You can either install MCrypt (which you should do anyway) or mark that specific test as one [requiring MCrypt](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.requires.tables.api). The latter will cause the test to be skipped if you don't have MCrypt installed.